# Pivot in custom module odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm try create pivot in custom module, but get error TypeError: 
init() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

```py
class ReportMyModuleUser(models.Model):
    _name = "report.my.module.user"
    _description = "My module"
    _auto = False


    name = fields.Char(string = 'Name')
    date = fields.Datetime(string = 'Date')
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'User')


    def _select(self):
        select_str = """
             SELECT
                    pn.name,
                    pn.date,
                    pn.user_id
        """
        return select_str

    def _group_by(self):
        group_by_str = """
                GROUP BY
                    pn.name
        """
        return group_by_str

    def init(self):
        print(self)
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, self._table)
        self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE view %s as
              %s
              FROM my_table pn
                %s
         """ % (self._table, self._select(), self._group_by()))
```

Any solution where is problem?

Maybe is problem in .xml file? I don't have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage one api on above of the init as like below.

`@api.model_cr
    def init(self):
        print(self)
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, self._table)
        self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE view %s as
              %s
              FROM my_table pn
                %s
         """ % (self._table, self._select(), self._group_by()))`

Your issue will resolve.

Or you can write your code in OLD api as below.

`def init(self, cr):
        print(self)
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
        cr.execute("""
            CREATE or REPLACE VIEW report_my_module_user as
              %s
              FROM my_table pn
                %s
         """ % (self._select(), self._group_by()))`

Comment: Hello, after add @api.model_cr before init get error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model_cr'

Comment: When put  api.model get erro  return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: old_api() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Make sure api must be there in import statement, `fields, models, api` all those three must be there.

Comment: On the top I have from openerp import tools, api, osv, fields, models, _

Comment: With old api   ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 7:               FROM my_table pn
                      ^

Comment: Please do the small changes inside "init" method as updated inside answer for OLD api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144651/discussion-between-user-odoo-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).